I am unable to call the compute task deployed in Apache Ignite server Mode from the thin or thick client defined in another project
Below is my code
For the server side
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Configuration
public class IgniteMainConfig {

    @Value("${kubernetes.namespace:}")
    private String kubernetesNamespace;

    @Value("${kubernetes.service_name:}")
    private String kubernetesServiceName;


    @Bean
    public Slf4jLogger igniteLogger() {
        return new Slf4jLogger();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Ignite igniteInstance(IgniteConfiguration igniteConfiguration) {
        return Ignition.start(igniteConfiguration);
    }

    /**
     * This is only used for local development. In the Ignite K8 config which is deployed it uses the
     * configuration from the Docker container.
     * 
     * @param cacheConfigs
     * @return
     * @throws NoSuchFieldException
     */
    @Bean
    public IgniteConfiguration igniteConfiguration(
            Slf4jLogger logger,
            Optional<IgniteDiscoverySpi> discoverySpi,
            @Qualifier("cacheConfiguration") CacheConfiguration<?,?>[] cacheConfigs
        ) throws NoSuchFieldException {
        IgniteConfiguration igniteCfg = new IgniteConfiguration();

        //uncomment this code for using persistance cache
         /*igniteCfg.setDataStorageConfiguration(new DataStorageConfiguration()
                .setDefaultDataRegionConfiguration(
                        new DataRegionConfiguration()
                                .setPersistenceEnabled(true) // Enable persistence
                ));*/

        /*igniteCfg.setConsistentId("node1");
        igniteCfg.setIgniteInstanceName("Ins1");*/

        // Add all cache configurations to IgniteConfiguration
        igniteCfg.setCacheConfiguration(cacheConfigs);
        igniteCfg.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true);
        igniteCfg.setDeploymentMode(DeploymentMode.CONTINUOUS);
        igniteCfg.setGridLogger(logger);

        ThinClientConfiguration thinClientCfg = new ThinClientConfiguration()
                .setMaxActiveComputeTasksPerConnection(100);

        ClientConnectorConfiguration clientConnectorCfg = new ClientConnectorConfiguration()
                .setThinClientConfiguration(thinClientCfg);

        igniteCfg.setClientConnectorConfiguration(clientConnectorCfg);

        discoverySpi.ifPresent(discovery -> igniteCfg.setDiscoverySpi(discovery));

//        Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(igniteCfg);
//
//        for (ClusterNode node : ignite.cluster().nodes()) {
//            System.out.println("Node IP: " + node.addresses());
//        }
        //igniteCfg.setClientConnectorConfiguration(new ClientConnectorConfiguration().setPort(10800));  // Adjust the port as needed

        //uncomment this code for using persistance cache
        /*ignite.cluster().active(true);*/

        return igniteCfg;
    }
    
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnPropertyNotEmpty("kubernetes.namespace")
    public IgniteDiscoverySpi discoverySpi(TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder kubernetesDiscovery) {
        var discoverySpi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();
        discoverySpi.setIpFinder(kubernetesDiscovery);
        return discoverySpi;
    }
    
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnPropertyNotEmpty("kubernetes.namespace")
    public TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder kubernetesDiscovery() {
        var k8sConfig = new KubernetesConnectionConfiguration();
        k8sConfig.setNamespace(kubernetesNamespace);
        k8sConfig.setServiceName(kubernetesServiceName);
        return new TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder(k8sConfig);
    }

}

And I have a service in the same project where I have deployed it locally by below code snippet
 Ignite ignite = Ignition.ignite();
        ignite.getOrCreateCache(cacheCfg);
        ignite.compute().localDeployTask(PersonCacheTask.class, PersonCacheTask.class.getClassLoader());

and the Task is defined as below kept at server side
@ComputeTaskName("PersonCacheTask")
public class PersonCacheTask extends ComputeTaskAdapter<List<Integer>, Integer> {

    @IgniteInstanceResource
    private Ignite ignite;

    // Map step: Splitting the task into jobs
    @Override
    public Map<? extends ComputeJob, ClusterNode> map(List<ClusterNode> subgrid, List<Integer> keys) throws IgniteException {
        IgniteCache<Integer, BinaryObject> cache = ignite.cache("personCache").withKeepBinary();

        Map<ComputeJob, ClusterNode> jobs = new HashMap<>();

        for (Integer key : keys) {
            jobs.put(new ComputeJobAdapter() {
                @Override
                public Object execute() {

                    // Perform any necessary processing
                    return 1; // Example result
                }
            }, subgrid.get(0)); // Assign the job to a cluster node
        }

        return jobs;
    }

    // Reduce step: Aggregating the results
    @Override
    public Integer reduce(List<ComputeJobResult> results) throws IgniteException {
        // Combine results from all jobs
        return 1; // Example: Sum the results
    }
}

Now at the client side
This is how I get the configuration
public static IgniteClient createThinClient() {
        ClientConfiguration cfg = new ClientConfiguration()
                .setAddresses(Constants.CLUSTER_IP_ADDRESS + ":" + Constants.CLUSTER_THIN_CLIENT_PORT)
                .setClusterDiscoveryEnabled(true)
                .setPartitionAwarenessEnabled(true)
                .setSslMode(SslMode.DISABLED)
                .setTimeout(10000);
        return Ignition.startClient(cfg);
    }

    public static Ignite createThickClient() {
        IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration()
                .setDiscoverySpi(new TcpDiscoverySpi().setIpFinder(new TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder().setAddresses(Collections.singleton(Constants.CLUSTER_IP_ADDRESS + ":" + Constants.CLUSTER_DISCOVERY_PORT))))
                .setCommunicationSpi(new TcpCommunicationSpi().setForceClientToServerConnections(false))
                .setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true)
                .setDeploymentMode(DeploymentMode.CONTINUOUS)
                .setClientMode(true);

        Ignition.setClientMode(true);
        return Ignition.start(cfg);
    }

And below is how I execute the code from the client side
Via thick client
IgniteCompute compute = client.compute(client.cluster().forRemotes());


            List<Integer> keys = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
            Integer result = client.compute().execute(PersonCacheTask.class, keys);
            System.out.println("Task result: " + result);

Via thin client
List<Integer> keys = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
            Integer result = client.compute().execute(PersonCacheTask.class.getName(), keys);
            System.out.println("Task result: " + result);

I get this log on the server side
2024-12-26 12:45:03.773  INFO 9028 --- [           main] o.a.i.i.m.d.GridDeploymentLocalStore     : Task locally deployed: class packageName.PersonCacheTask
But when I try to execute via thin client I get below logs
Caused by: org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.ClientServerError: Ignite failed to process request [4]: Unknown task name or failed to auto-deploy task (was task (re|un)deployed?): packageName.PersonCacheTask (server status code [1])
Also below logs
Ignite failed to process request [4]: Failed to map task jobs to nodes due to undeclared user exception [cause=null, ses=GridTaskSessionImpl [taskName=PersonCacheTask, dep=GridDeployment [ts=1735197303767, depMode=CONTINUOUS, clsLdr=jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@368239c8, clsLdrId=72881d10491-ca4b8bdc-e6ff-47ea-949b-cf8b2011936e, userVer=0, loc=true, sampleClsName=packageName.PersonCacheTask, pendingUndeploy=false, undeployed=false, usage=1], taskClsName=package.PersonCacheTask, sesId=59e81d10491-ca4b8bdc-e6ff-47ea-949b-cf8b2011936e, startTime=1735198790734, endTime=9223372036854775807, taskNodeId=ca4b8bdc-e6ff-47ea-949b-cf8b2011936e, clsLdr=jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@368239c8, closed=false, cpSpi=null, failSpi=null, loadSpi=null, usage=1, fullSup=false, internal=false, topPred=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.client.compute.ClientComputeTask$$Lambda$1452/0x00000008009dfc40@3a8d6b59, mapFut=IgniteFuture [orig=GridFutureAdapter [ignoreInterrupts=false, state=INIT, res=null, hash=1457235860]], execName=null, secCtx=null]] (server status code [1])
